# Trying to get right portion of string

Tags: sql, sql-server

New to SQL here, I'm trying to get the last value in a string of variable length.

Column [Path] is set up like so...

```
Attributes\Objects\Heirarchies\<Taxonomy>\
Attributes\Objects\Heirarchies\<Taxonomy>\Animalia\
Attributes\Objects\Heirarchies\<Taxonomy>\Animalia\Chordata\
etc...
```

I want only the last value in the string. Things would be simple (simple for my skills anyways) if each string didn't end in a '\', found that out when I tried this:

```
SELECT RIGHT([Path], CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE([Path]))-1)
```

and...got nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've done some searching on here, but nothing seemed to work for my situation.

Cheers!

Comment: in your solution - you could TRIM the last char off the string - then everything else would work... (hint - not code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works perfectly for extracting file names from all kind of file paths

```
SELECT Reverse(Substring(Reverse(LEFT(@String, LEN(@String) - 1)),1,CharIndex('\',Reverse(LEFT(@String, LEN(@String) - 1)))-1))
```

Answer (score 2):

This works by dropping the last character off the path before applying your original sql

```
SELECT RIGHT([Path], CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE([Path]))-1) lastElement from
(
    select left( [path] , len([path]) -1 ) [path] from paths
) paths

-- example results
lastElement
<Taxonomy>
Animalia
Chordata
```

Supporting schema

```
CREATE TABLE paths
(
    [path] nvarchar(255)
)
GO

insert into paths( [path] ) values ('Attributes\Objects\Heirarchies\<Taxonomy>\')
insert into paths( [path] ) values ('Attributes\Objects\Heirarchies\<Taxonomy>\Animalia\')
insert into paths( [path] ) values ('Attributes\Objects\Heirarchies\<Taxonomy>\Animalia\Chordata\')
```

Comment: I didn't try this one because I got to the others first, but I appreciate you taking the time to respond!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(LEFT([Path], LEN([Path])-1)), CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(LEFT([Path], LEN([Path])-1)))-1))
```